# detect peaks in vertical projection histogram

Tags: python

Is there a way to detect the peaks in a  vertical projection profile and then determine their height and width (in python) as shown in the picture

[image: 1]

Comment: I would convert to a data set of x & y values then check for change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.